# Where would I ask about designing games indie-style

Tags: support, allowed-questions

From something like a 2D android app similar to chess with different mechanics though, to other styles of gaming like a shooter.

Where would I ask about what and how I could acquire a program like this. I've senn on steam "RPG MAKER" or "GAME GURU" and if thats the way to go, the next question is are they good and easy to understand. How much code is needed to know before jumping in, and all that.

Once I know here in meta, what stack site to ask this on I will rephrase it.

Let me know. I want to get into game design, any way possible.

Comment: [GameDevelopment.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you. And maybe to save another quick question, where would I go to ask about Wordpress?

Comment: There's [Wordpress.SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)!

Don't forget to read through their help centre articles on [on-topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) questions to make sure your questions are a good fit!

Generally if you find yourself getting question-banned, the best thing you can do is make sure you read these articles through and checking your question against them.

Comment: Right on. Im a year + in SCI FI with the option to vote in mods when the election comes. And thats where I have the most rep.

Im gonna stay away from the GDSE though, I asked a relevant question there and got kicked in the balls within two minutes.

Not as friendly...

Comment: @Sidhartha, unfortunately  some communities can come off as far more strict and unfriendly than others. GDSE is a tricky one... on one hand it's a great source for specific questions and such. On the other, they hate the whole beginner/how to start aspect... I would use them as a reference (like most SE networks), but I'd use another source for general how-tos and pointers for getting started.

Answer (score -1):

## [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Ask which software you should use for this game, including as much detail as possible about your goals and current skills. When you get an answer that you like, google online tutorials for that program.

GameDev can help if you get stuck with specific issues.